# Replace string with link in bash

Tags: bash

I want to replace a sentence in a file this:
from

```
[Report 1](**Please put link here**)"
[Report 2](**Please put link here**)
```

to:

```
[Report 1](https://stackoverflow.com/09004cffcbee784a?docno=/link1)"
[Report 2](https://stackoverflow.com/09004cffcbee784a?docno=/link2)
```

So I tried with but it does not seem to make the replacement

```
sed -i 's#[Report 1](\*\*Please put link here\*\*)#(https://stackoverflow.com/09004cffcbee784a?docno=/link1)#g' file.md
```

Comment: Where does the link come from? Should it be hardcoded?

Comment: @choroba yes, it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are special in sed regular expressions (they introduce character classes). You need to escape them by a backslash.

```
s#\[Report 1\)](\*\*Please put link here\*\*)#(https://stackoverflow.com/09004cffcbee784a?docno=/link1)#g
```

You may also capture the number after `Report` and resuse it in the link:

```
s#\[Report \([12]\)](\*\*Please put link here\*\*)#(https://stackoverflow.com/09004cffcbee784a?docno=/link\1)#g
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you don't need to use whole string as pattern, look for a sub-pattern to ease your quest, like this for example:

```
$ url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78192804/replace-string-with-link-in-bash'
$ echo '[Report 1](**Please put link here**)' | sed "s|\*.*\*|$url|"
[Report 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78192804/replace-string-with-link-in-bash)
```